# How to connect to the localhost of an Android emulator?

Tags: web, server, dart, flutter

Note that I'm not trying to connect to the localhost of the host machine from the Android emulator, I'm pretty much doing it in reverse - I started a server on the localhost inside Android emulator and want to connect to that localhost from the computer's browser.

I'm using [Angel](https://angel-dart.dev/) framework on Flutter.

```dart
import 'package:angel_framework/angel_framework.dart';
import 'package:angel_framework/http.dart';

Future<AngelHttp> startWebServer({int port = 3000}) async {
  var app = Angel();
  var http = AngelHttp(app);

  await http.startServer('localhost', port);
  print('Started HTTP server at ${http.server.address}:${http.server.port}');

  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.write('<p>Hello, world!<p>'));

  return http;
}
```

What settings should I put and what address should I use in my browser to receive 'Hello World' from the server running on the emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `adb forward`. See [port forwarding](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#forwardports)

```
adb forward tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```

Then on your computer you can connect to `http://localhost:3000` and it will be routed to port 3000 of the emulator.

Comment: That works! First add `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/` to PATH, then run `adb devices` to show current active devices, the run `adb -s [emulator-name] forward ... ...` solved my problem!! Thanks a lot!!!